# Almost identical programs. One works, one doesn't

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have 2 virtually identical programs. The only difference is the name of the class and hence one line of the program which refers to that name (to construct an instance of the class). The first runs fine. The line that's causing the problem (although it's in both programs and doesn't cause a problem in the first), which netbeans is reporting isn't a statement is
    panel.add(chartPanel);
Deatils of the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - not a statement
at splinepanel.SplinePanel.createContentPane(SplinePanel.java:139)
at splinepanel.SplinePanel.createAndShowGUI(SplinePanel.java:157)
at splinepanel.SplinePanel.access$000(SplinePanel.java:33)
at splinepanel.SplinePanel$1.run(SplinePanel.java:170)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Can anyone help please? The first program (which works) is called PanelExmpale.java. The second program which doesn't work is as follows:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package splinepanel;

/*

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
* 
* */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;       // Using AWT containers and components
import java.awt.event.*; // Using AWT events and listener interfaces
import javax.swing.*;    // Using Swing components and containers
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.data.general.Series;
import org.jfree.util.PublicCloneable;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYSplineRenderer;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class SplinePanel{

    public JPanel createContentPane(){
        // This is where we'll put all our widgets
        // in the next tutorials!
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        /*

        SplineFactory s = new SplineFactory(); 

        double[] c = new double[12];
    c[0]  =   0.0;  // x0
    c[1]  =   0.0;  // y0
    c[2]  =   0.0;  // z0      

    c[3]  =   1.0;  // x1
    c[4]  =   1.0;  // y1
    c[5]  =   0.0;  // z1      

    c[6]  =   2.0;  // x2
    c[7]  =  -1.0;  // y2
    c[8]  =   0.0;  // z2      

    c[9]  =  10.0;  // x3
    c[10] =   0.0;  // y3
    c[11] =   0.0;  // z3      

    double[] spline1 = SplineFactory.createBezier (c,     20);
    double[] spline2 = SplineFactory.createCubic (c,      20);
    double[] spline3 = SplineFactory.createCatmullRom (c, 20); 

    /*

    System.out.println ("-- Bezier");
    for (int i = 0; i < spline1.length; i+=3)
      System.out.println (spline1[i] + "," + spline1[i+1] + "," + spline1[i+2]);

    System.out.println ("-- Cubic");
    for (int i = 0; i < spline2.length; i+=3)
      System.out.println (spline2[i] + "," + spline2[i+1] + "," + spline2[i+2]);

    System.out.println ("-- Catmull-Rom");
    for (int i = 0; i < spline3.length; i+=3)
      System.out.println (spline3[i] + "," + spline3[i+1] + "," + spline3[i+2]);

    */



        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("MyGraph");

        /*

        System.out.println ("-- Bezier");
        for (int i = 0; i < spline1.length; i+=3)
         System.out.println (spline1[i] + "," + spline1[i+1] + "," + spline1[i+2]);
        // series.add(spline1[i])

        System.out.println ("-- Cubic");
        for (int i = 0; i < spline2.length; i+=3)
         System.out.println (spline2[i] + "," + spline2[i+1] + "," + spline2[i+2]);

        System.out.println ("-- Catmull-Rom");
        for (int i = 0; i < spline3.length; i+=3)
         System.out.println (spline3[i] + "," + spline3[i+1] + "," + spline3[i+2]); 

         */

        /* 
        series.add(0, 1);
        series.add(1, 2);
        series.add(2, 5);
        series.add(7, 8);
        series.add(9, 10);
        */

         series.add(0, 1);
        series.add(1, 2);
        series.add(2, 5);
        series.add(7, 8);
        series.add(9, 10);

        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(series);

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                "XY Chart",
                "x-axis",
                "y-axis",
                dataset, 
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true,
                true,
                false
                );
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);

        //chart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(new XYSplineRenderer());





        panel.add(chartPanel);
        //panel.setSize(800, 500);

        //content panes must be opaque



        panel.setOpaque(true); 
        return panel;  
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("[=] There's a JPanel in here! [=]");

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        SplinePanel demo = new SplinePanel();
        frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

        // The other bits and pieces that make our program a bit more stable.
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1300, 650);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Running a clean and build leads to 100 errors, the first of which is:

```
error: duplicate class: org.jfree.experimental.chart.demo.CombinedCategoryPlotDemo1 
public class CombinedCategoryPlotDemo1 extends ApplicationFrame {
```

Comment: Just to check (because sometimes weird things happen); have you tried doing a clean and build (assuming you're using an IDE)

Comment: no: I'll try, Godwilling

Comment: this code compiles & runs fine for me

Comment: which is line 139 in SplinePanel.java?

Comment: lol- reminds me of yesterday

Comment: No doubt a netbeans problem - try rebuilding

Comment: panel.add(chartPanel); @Aniket

Comment: import javax.swing.*; is redundant

Comment: ok, thanks @GMZ: becuae it's there twice you mean?

Comment: clean and build gives 100 errors, the first of which is Created dir: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SplinePanel\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 2334 source files to C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SplinePanel\build\classes
C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SplinePanel\src\lib\jfreechart-1.0.16\jfreechart-1.0.16\experimental\org\jfree\experimental\chart\demo\CombinedCategoryPlotDemo1.java:64: error: duplicate class: org.jfree.experimental.chart.demo.CombinedCategoryPlotDemo1
public class CombinedCategoryPlotDemo1 extends ApplicationFrame {

Comment: sorry first error is error: duplicate class: org.jfree.experimental.chart.demo.CombinedCategoryPlotDemo1
public class CombinedCategoryPlotDemo1 extends ApplicationFrame {

Comment: why don't you try taking the first program that works and refactor it using netbeans to the name of the second class. I hope that works, and shows you where the culprit lies in the current code.

Comment: These things are usually; (1) a name clash or (2) netbeans keeping a cashe of old compiled code and getting confused

Comment: refactoring names in netbeans is awkward

Comment: And make sure that **SplinePanel** is in **SplinePanel.java**

Comment: @bluesh34 It is? You just right click --> refactor --> rename. The whole 'the dialogue not fitting on the screen on small monitors' problem asside (grumble grumble)

Comment: What i'm trying to do is keep PanelExample as it does something I want, but create SplinePanel which is to use features of PanelExample but do other stuff: i don't want to lose PanelExample: I'm sure this should be possible: I've no idea why it should be so difficult

Comment: I tried removing and reinserting the API I'm using. Now I get this error for the same line: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: javax.swing.JPanel.add

Comment: What i'm trying to do is just like 'save as' in Word or any software when you want to save a draft, but netbeans throws a wobbly- weird. this is one of those ones where you just sit and stare at the screen, completely bemused

Comment: duplicate classes is the error again now

Comment: I think I've finally given up on NetBeans- time for Eclipse

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4):

As noted in comments and shown below, your code runs fine. It looks like you've got more than needed on the *classpath* in your build environment. On the command line, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19073029/230513), you typically need just `jfreechart` and `jcommon`. In NetBeans, check the Library Manager, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1976322/230513) and below.

NetBeans Ant Library Manager showing `JFreeChart`:

[image: Ant Library Manager]

Image, as run:

[image]

Code, as run:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

public class SplinePanel {

    public JPanel createContentPane() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("MyGraph");
        series.add(0, 1);
        series.add(1, 2);
        series.add(2, 5);
        series.add(7, 8);
        series.add(9, 10);
        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(series);
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            "XY Chart",
            "x-axis",
            "y-axis",
            dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            true,
            true,
            false);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        panel.add(chartPanel);
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        return panel;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("[=] There's a JPanel in here! [=]");
        SplinePanel demo = new SplinePanel();
        frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The jars in the classpath are identical to those for the program which works. netBeans reported a duplicate class error. I read on another similar question that clearing the netbeans cache solved the problem. I can't find jfreechart-1.0.16.jar. I only have jfreechart-1.0.16-demo.jar, but this is what I used for the progam which works, as I said.

Comment: The JARs, as built, are in the `lib` directory of the distribution; I haven't had to nuke the cache in a while, but it may help; try building from the command line, too.

Comment: I found an easier solution: swiching to Eclipse!